# Customização de EditText no Android

Tags: android

Eu vi que existe varias maneiras de se customizar um `EditText`, uma delas é em *background* e a outra é *XML*.

Qual seria a melhor opção? Será que tem desvantagem em usar background ou dá na mesma?

Comment: Ao meu ver os dois tem as mesmas finalidades mas o background é mais complexo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor forma customizar ou dar estilo a uma `EditText`, assim como qualquer outra `view`, é criando um ficheiro xml dedicado pra tal.

Um ficheiro dedicado a customização garante:

- Reutilização;
- Organização;
- Fácil acesso;

Por exemplo, eu quero criar uma `editText` com as bordas curvas/arredondadas.

Primeiro eu vou criar  um ficheiro xml onde irei colocar todos os atributos de estilo: **rounded_edittext.xml**

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#862f99" />
        <corners
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:topRightRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"/>
    </shape>
```

Agora eu posso adicionar o estilo à minha `editText` definido o `background` da seguinte forma:

```
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp" />
```

E já está'

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mais info: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml